# @ForeignCollectionField is missed in ORMLite 4.9?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have downloaded both `ormlite-android-4.9.jar` and `ormlite-core-4.9.jar`
From [maven central repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/j256/ormlite/) and put them into `app/orm` folder.
After that I set dependency to this libraries:

#### build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('orm/ormlite-android-4.9.jar')
    compile files('orm/ormlite-core-4.9.jar')
}
```

All was good until I try to set `@ForeignCollectionField` to one of class fields.

[image: demonstration]

Official docs told me that `@ForeignCollectionField` [still used in nowadays](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ForeignCollectionField%20). 
The logical question: what I'm missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Official docs told me that `@ForeignCollectionField` still used in nowadays. 
>   The logical question: what I'm missed?

It certainly is used but it was [added in 4.16](http://ormlite.com/changelog.txt) and you are using version 4.9.

The latest release number is [4.48 from the central repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.j256.ormlite%22).  You need to be careful because 4.9 sorts lower on the list than 4.48.  Yeah it's dumb but I don't control the directory order.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simpliest.

I download `*.jar` from incorrect resource. 
Looks like in [Maven repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/j256/ormlite/) ORMLite guys stores dev(beta?) builds.

The correct link for downloading : http://ormlite.com/releases/